# Channel entry notification isn't working on entries created by SafeCracker

Tags: safecracker, channel, entry, notification

Channel entry notifications are not working on new entries generated by SafeCracker. This seems to be a recent development, as the notifications were working previously. The only change has been in updating EE versions and a change to the client's SMTP servers. We tried switching to PHP and Sendmail, and now are working with a new SMTP account.

I believe I've narrowed it to a problem between SafeCracker and the channel. Email notifications are working via FreeForm and Tools > Communicate.

Strangely, I did receive 2 new entry notifications via the forms submitted by real users, but the client (whose email address was also in the recipients list) did not, and I was unable to replicate success using test form submissions.

Channel entry notifications do work just fine when manually adding a new entry in the Control Panel.

Has anyone experience something similar to this, or have any ideas about what might be preventing notifications from being sent?

EE version 2.5.2

Comment: Stupid question, did the successful notifications go to the clients spam/trash folder?  Also, is the SMTP coming from/going to the same location for the client?

Comment: Can you verify that the system is in fact able to send email? Try sending a password reset message.

Comment: @lucas- nothing in the spam folder, and I believe the SMTP is a separate Verizon account, not being used for typical email.

Comment: @PhilipZaengle yes, the system can send email. Verified that through the Tools > Communicate module. The problem seems to be resolved for the moment, although can't pinpoint exactly what the cause was. I tried removing and re-adding the recipient emails in EE and creating a form from a brand new account, and it send the notifications successfully. The only thing I can think of is that the new account used a different email address than my initial test account. Perhaps EE doesn't send notifications if the email address that generated the entry is the same as the notification recipient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the email method to IMAP, and creating a new user to test from, the notifications began coming through again. Not sure what exactly broke it loose, but wondering if it was an issue with the mail server after all.

Comment: You also need to be logged out when you test it..

Comment: "You also need to be logged out when you test it" This caught me out. Was working as it should, I was just logged in to the control panel. Testing from a different browser solved the issue. Thanks @Benoit L

Answer (score 3):

The entries API notifications are triggered at around line 1858 of Api_channel_entries.php. A few `var_dump()`s in that area should be enough to determine a) whether the notifications are being triggered at all and b) where the system is attempting to send them to.